# I am using NSwag with an ASP.Net Core API and the Swagger UI client is displaying

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I am using NSwag with an ASP.Net Core API, when I execute the web API and navigates to the Swagger UI it displays the following error:

Fetching resource list: undefined. Please wait. It gives an 404 and tells me that Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined, that when I tried to trace the error is pointing to the Swagger client in self.url.substring. Although the json displayed in the swagger.json is totally correct.

This is my Startup.cs class with the Explorer Solution at the right showing my nuget dependencies:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Enable the Swagger UI middleware and the Swagger generator
        app.UseSwaggerUi(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, settings =>
        {
            settings.SwaggerUiRoute = "/swagger";
            settings.PostProcess = document =>
            {
                document.Info.Version = "v1";
                document.Info.Title = "Analisis API";
                document.Info.Description = "A simple ASP.NET Core web API";
                document.Info.TermsOfService = "None";
                document.Info.Contact = new NSwag.SwaggerContact
                {
                    Name = "Example",
                    Email = "example@gmail.com",
                    Url = "http://google.es"
                };
                document.Info.License = new NSwag.SwaggerLicense
                {
                    Name = "Use under LICX",
                    Url = "https://example.com/license"
                };
            };

            app.UseMvc();
        });
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    public IDatosAnalisis datosManager = new DatosAnalisis();
    public IResultado resultadoManager = new Resultado();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<String> GetDefault()
    {
        return "Bienvenido a AnalisisApi";
    }

    [HttpGet("getResultado/{patologiaId}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResultadoDTO), 200)]
    public ActionResult<ResultadoDTO> GetResultadoByPatologiaId(int patologiaId)
    {
        ResultadoDTO result = resultadoManager.getResultadoByPatologia(patologiaId);

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Receives the analisis data and evaluates them.
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<List<ShortResultDTO>> TestValoresAnalisis(DatosSujetoDTO datosSujeto)
    {
        List<ShortResultDTO> results = datosManager.postDatosAnalisisAndGetPatologias(datosSujeto);

        return results;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, my workaround: using a custom url to visit Swagger

> https://localhost:44336/swagger/index.html?url=/swagger/v1/swagger.json

Comment: Thanks for your response Jiping, I can see also the swagger.json on screen but I continue not being able to show the Swagger interface. At the end I have the info, but I am wondering why the interface is not working.